# Swing JMenuBar not rendering properly

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

First time actually using anything to do with swing - sorry for the poor code and crude visuals!
Using swing for a massively over-complicated password checker school project, and when I came to loading in a JMenuBar, it doesn't render properly the first time. Once I run through one of the options first, it reloads correctly, but the first time it comes out like this:
[First render attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uciq3.png)

But after I run one of the methods, either by clicking one of the buttons that I added to check if it was just the JFrame that was broken or using one of the broken menu options, it reloads correctly, but has a little grey bar above where the JMenuBar actually renders: [Post-method render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avdxl.png)

The code for the visuals is as follows:

```
public void draw_menu(){
        this.parent.pack();
        this.parent.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        JButton check = new JButton("Check Password");
        JButton generate = new JButton("Generate Password");
        generate.addActionListener(e -> this.generator());
        check.addActionListener(e -> this.char_checker());
        check.setBounds(500,500, 170, 50);
        generate.setBounds(500, 200, 170, 50);
        this.parent.add(check);
        this.parent.add(generate);
        JMenu a = new JMenu("Check Password");
        JMenu b = new JMenu("Generate Password");
        JMenu c = new JMenu("Extra Codes");
        JMenuItem a1 = new JMenuItem("Enter password >>>");
        JMenuItem b1 = new JMenuItem("Generate >>>");
        JMenuItem c1 = new JMenuItem("Valid >>>");
        JMenuItem c2 = new JMenuItem("Why >>>");
        a1.addActionListener(e -> this.char_checker());
        b1.addActionListener(e -> this.generator());
        c1.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Password.this.parent, Arrays.asList(valid_chars).toString(), "Valid Characters", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));
        c2.addActionListener(e -> this.why());
        a.add(a1);
        b.add(b1);
        c.add(c1);
        c.add(c2);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(a);
        menuBar.add(b);
        menuBar.add(c);
        this.parent.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        this.parent.add(menuBar);
        this.parent.setVisible(true);
    }
```

If you want to have the whole file to contextualize it (and be able to run it) you can view it below:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Password {

    Scanner scanner;
    String password;
    Integer score;
    List<Character> pass;
    JFrame parent;
    JLabel frameScore;

    static Character[] valid_chars = {'!', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+'};
    static Character[] lower_alpha = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    static Character[] upper_alpha = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    static Character[] valid_nums = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    static String[] keyboard_combos = {"qwe", "wer", "ert", "rty", "tyu", "yui", "uio", "iop", "asd", "sdf", "dfg", "fgh", "gjh", "hjk", "jkl", "zxc", "xcv", "cvb", "vbn", "bnm"};

    boolean num = false;
    boolean upper = false;
    boolean lower = false;
    boolean character = false;

    public Password() {
    }

    public void why() throws NullPointerException {
        if (Objects.isNull(this.score)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "Try checking a password first!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println("Error -> this.score returns null!\t|\tTry checking a password first!");
            this.draw_menu();
        }
        String out = "Your password achieved a score of "+this.score.toString()+" because you included ";
        if (this.num){out = out.concat("at least one number, ");}
        if (this.character){out = out.concat("at least one special character, ");}
        if (this.upper){out = out.concat("at least one upper case letter, ");}
        if (this.lower){out = out.concat("at least one lower case letter, ");}
        out  = out.concat("Achieving your score of: "+this.score.toString());
        System.out.println(out);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, out, "Score: "+this.score.toString(), JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        this.draw_menu();
    }
    public void char_checker() {
        this.password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this.parent, "Enter your password:", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (this.password.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error <- this.password.length() returns null!\t|\tTry entering a password!");
        }
        if (this.password.length() < 8 || this.password.length() > 24) {
            System.out.println("Error <- this.password.length() exceeds bounds!\t|\t( [Bounds 7 < password < 24] String length = "+this.password.length()+")");
        } else {
            char[] pass_array = this.password.toCharArray();
            for (Character temp : pass_array) {
                if (Arrays.asList(valid_chars).contains(temp) || Arrays.asList(lower_alpha).contains(temp) || Arrays.asList(upper_alpha).contains(temp) || Arrays.asList(valid_nums).contains(temp)) {
                    System.out.print("valid placement @ temp:" + temp);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("\nError <- $temp: '" + temp + "' not found in character bank!\t|\tNot valid character (alphanumerical + valid_chars only)\nEnter valid on menu for more information.");
                    this.draw_menu();
                }
            }
            this.security_score(pass_array);
        }
        this.draw_menu();
    }

    public void security_score(char[] array){
        if (!Objects.isNull(this.frameScore)){
            this.frameScore.setText("");
        }
        this.num = false;
        this.upper = false;
        this.lower = false;
        this.character = false;
        System.out.println("\nGenerating security score...");
        this.score = 0;
        this.score = this.password.length();
        for (Character temp: array) {
            if (Arrays.asList(valid_chars).contains(temp)) {
                if (!this.character) {
                    this.score = this.score + 5;
                    this.character = true;
                }
            } else if (Arrays.asList(valid_nums).contains(temp)){
                if (!this.num){
                    this.score = this.score + 5;
                    this.num = true;
                }
            } else if (Arrays.asList(lower_alpha).contains(temp)){
                if (!this.lower){
                    this.score = this.score + 5;
                    this.lower = true;
                }
            } else if (Arrays.asList(upper_alpha).contains(temp)){
                if (!this.upper){
                    this.score = this.score + 5;
                    this.upper = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (this.lower && this.upper && this.character && this.num){
            this.score = this.score + 10;
        } else if (!this.character && !this.num) {
            this.score = this.score - 5;
        } else if (!this.character && !this.lower && !this.upper){
            this.score = this.score - 5;
        } else if (!this.lower && !this.upper && !this.num){
            this.score = this.score - 5;
        }
        for (String temp : keyboard_combos){
            if (this.password.contains(temp)) {
                this.score = this.score - 5;
            }
        }

        if (this.score > 20){
            System.out.println("With a score of "+this.score+", your password is Strong.");
        } else if (this.score < 20 && this.score > 0){
            System.out.println("With a score of "+this.score+", your password is Average.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("With a score of "+this.score+", your password is Weak.");
        }
        System.out.println("To see why you achieved a score of "+this.score.toString()+", enter \"why\" on the menu!");
        this.frameScore = new JLabel("<html>Your previous score was: "+this.score.toString()+"<br/>with:"+this.password+"</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        Dimension size = this.frameScore.getPreferredSize();
        this.frameScore.setBounds(150, 100, size.width, size.height);
        this.parent.setLayout(null);
        this.parent.add(this.frameScore);
    }

    public void generator() {
        if (!Objects.isNull(this.frameScore)){
            this.frameScore.setText("");
        }
        if (!Objects.isNull(this.score)) {
            this.frameScore = new JLabel("<html>Your previous score was: " + this.score + "<br/>with:" + this.password + "</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        }
        this.pass.clear();
        System.out.println("generating password...");
        int length = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(8, 12);
        System.out.println(length);
        int count = 0;
        int item;
        while (count < length - 1){
            int choice = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 4);
            switch (choice){
                case 1:
                    item = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, valid_chars.length);
                    this.pass.add(valid_chars[item]);
                    count++;

                case 2:
                    item = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, lower_alpha.length);
                    this.pass.add(lower_alpha[item]);
                    count++;

                case 3:
                    item = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, upper_alpha.length);
                    this.pass.add(upper_alpha[item]);
                    count++;

                case 4:
                    item = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, valid_nums.length);
                    this.pass.add(valid_nums[item]);
                    count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your password is:");
        char[] array = new char[this.pass.size()];
        for (char temp : this.pass){
            System.out.print(temp);
            array[this.pass.indexOf(temp)] = this.pass.get(this.pass.indexOf(temp));
        }
        this.password = String.valueOf(array);
        this.security_score(array);
        System.out.println("Generation complete!");
        if (this.score < 20){
            this.generator();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "<html>Generation complete!<br/>"+this.password+"</html>", "Generated!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        this.draw_menu();
    }

    //visual rendering code
    public void draw_menu(){
        this.parent.pack();
        this.parent.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        JButton check = new JButton("Check Password");
        JButton generate = new JButton("Generate Password");
        generate.addActionListener(e -> this.generator());
        check.addActionListener(e -> this.char_checker());
        check.setBounds(500,500, 170, 50);
        generate.setBounds(500, 200, 170, 50);
        this.parent.add(check);
        this.parent.add(generate);
        JMenu a = new JMenu("Check Password");
        JMenu b = new JMenu("Generate Password");
        JMenu c = new JMenu("Extra Codes");
        JMenuItem a1 = new JMenuItem("Enter password >>>");
        JMenuItem b1 = new JMenuItem("Generate >>>");
        JMenuItem c1 = new JMenuItem("Valid >>>");
        JMenuItem c2 = new JMenuItem("Why >>>");
        a1.addActionListener(e -> this.char_checker());
        b1.addActionListener(e -> this.generator());
        c1.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Password.this.parent, Arrays.asList(valid_chars).toString(), "Valid Characters", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));
        c2.addActionListener(e -> this.why());
        a.add(a1);
        b.add(b1);
        c.add(c1);
        c.add(c2);
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(a);
        menuBar.add(b);
        menuBar.add(c);
        this.parent.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        this.parent.add(menuBar);
        this.parent.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Password user = new Password();
        user.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        user.pass = new ArrayList<>();
        user.parent = new JFrame();
        user.draw_menu();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you call `this.parent.add(menuBar)` when you already added it via `this.parent.setJMenuBar(menuBar)` (in the previous line)? Also, you should separate adding the buttons from the menu creation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I had both because without the this.parent.add(menuBar) all the buttons become weird sizes (specifically the generate button takes up the entire frame) although it does get rid of the little grey bar where the menuBar should be... I'll try adding the buttons to a JFrame and setting the boundaries for that to fix the problem with the buttons becoming massive... Also should i add them to the frame in a separate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate creating your menu from your content. Please review the following example. I decoupled your menu, component, and event logic into meaningful phases.

```java
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class App implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6924949643971067836L;

    private static final Character[] VALID_CHARS = {'!', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '-', '_', '=', '+'};
    private static final Character[] LOWER_ALPHA = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
    private static final Character[] UPPER_ALPHA = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
    private static final Character[] VALID_NUMS = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'};
    private static final String[] KEYBOARD_COMBOS = {"qwe", "wer", "ert", "rty", "tyu", "yui", "uio", "iop", "asd", "sdf", "dfg", "fgh", "gjh", "hjk", "jkl", "zxc", "xcv", "cvb", "vbn", "bnm"};
    
    private Scanner scanner;
    private String password;
    private Integer score;
    private List<Character> pass;
    private JFrame parent;
    private JLabel frameScore;

    private boolean num = false;
    private boolean upper = false;
    private boolean lower = false;
    private boolean character = false;
    
    public App() { }
    
    private void checkPassword() {
        System.out.println("Checking password...");
    }

    private void generatePassword() {
        System.out.println("Generating password...");
    }
    
    private void why() {
        System.out.println("Why...");
    }
    
    protected JPanel createContent() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton check = new JButton("Check Password");
        JButton generate = new JButton("Generate Password");
        
        check.addActionListener(e -> this.checkPassword());
        generate.addActionListener(e -> this.generatePassword());
        
        check.setBounds(500,500, 170, 50);
        generate.setBounds(500, 200, 170, 50);
        
        mainPanel.add(check);
        mainPanel.add(generate);
        
        return mainPanel;
    }
    
    protected JMenuBar createMenu() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu checkPass = new JMenu("Check Password");
        JMenu resetPass = new JMenu("Generate Password");
        JMenu extraCodes = new JMenu("Extra Codes");
        
        JMenuItem enterPass = new JMenuItem("Enter password >>>");
        JMenuItem generatePass = new JMenuItem("Generate >>>");
        JMenuItem verify = new JMenuItem("Valid >>>");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("Why >>>");
        
        enterPass.addActionListener(e -> this.checkPassword());
        generatePass.addActionListener(e -> this.generatePassword());
        verify.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.parent, Arrays.asList(VALID_CHARS).toString(), "Valid Characters", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE));
        about.addActionListener(e -> this.why());
        
        menuBar.add(checkPass);
        menuBar.add(resetPass);
        menuBar.add(extraCodes);
        
        checkPass.add(enterPass);
        resetPass.add(generatePass);
        extraCodes.add(verify);
        extraCodes.add(about);
        
        return menuBar;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.parent = new JFrame();
        
        this.parent.setJMenuBar(createMenu());
        this.parent.setContentPane(createContent());
        this.parent.pack();
        this.parent.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.parent.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new App());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```